# How to dynamically filter report by month in the same year in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to filter my report to only get data for every current month in the current year based on the date column in powerbi. how do I create a measure to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
ThisMonthMeasure = 
CALCULATE ( 
    [MyMeasure], 
    FILTER ( 
        'Calendar', 
        MONTH ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) = MONTH ( NOW() ) &&
        YEAR ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) = YEAR ( NOW() )
    )
)
```